# How to use sorting by two values including datatime properly in Room?

Tags: android

As in topic, how to use sorting by two values including datatime properly in Room?
My dataString = "02/03/2012", so format dd/MM/YYYY.

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM notification_list ORDER BY isRead ASC, STR_TO_DATE(data,\"%d-%m-%Y\") DESC")
    abstract suspend fun readAllData(): List<NotificationItemsResponse.NotificationItemData>
```

```
error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such function: STR_TO_DATE)
    public abstract java.lang.Object readAllData(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

I also have found method with convert, but it doesn't work as well with similar error.

Does room with sqLite have inner methods that I could use?
What is a solution for this?

Comment: Please check [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-time-2b4cf9672b98)

Comment: Thank you it should fix the problem:)